# How to separate different item types into different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to sql based databases, what I'm trying to implement is an inventory system where each user can have infinite amount of items with more than 20 item types.
What I'm trying right now is:

having an `items` table where I keep track of all the items the user has.

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL
    )
```

and upon request to get all of the items, I `SELECT` items with user_id from `items` table and then `SELECT` for each table_name which ends up `SELECT` ing for each item type ( like 10-20 queries per user ) and if I want to delete an item I have to do it for two tables which is a pain and I really think there's a better way for this ( I request for each table only once but still )
any help is appreciated a lot!

Comment: It's generally poor design to use dynamic table names. You can't use variables in queries for the table name, unless you write stored procedures that create the queries dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic information should be in table contents, not table and column names.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, that's kind of my question as well, what do you suggest?

Comment: Use an attribute-value table for the item attributes.

Comment: So you don't need to have custom tables for each item type.

Comment: @Barmar an example or external link is appreciated a lot! I could not find what you mentioned exactly

Comment: https://looker.com/blog/sql-processing-and-data-analysis-with-the-eav-model